# Check if asynchronous upload is in progress

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I have an upload script that uses XMLHttpRequests and I also make use of the html5 history api. I need to check if an upload is in progress so that if a user navigates back to the upload page the progress of the upload will be shown.

Here's what I have tried;

```
$(document).on("changePage", function(){ 
    //changePage is the trigger I have created that is fired whenever the page is changed
    if(typeof xhr != 'undefined'){
        if(xhr.upload.onprogress){
            uploading_tools();
        } 
    }
});
```

Through a few tests I have realised that `xhr` becomes undefined whenever you navigate away from the upload page. This is unlike the html5 `audio` element. I also use html5 audio on the site I am working on and I test if the `audio` is defined in the same way with success.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the same page that stays open during the upload, then you can just use some state (e.g. your own variable) to track when the upload starts and when it completes and then you can check that state at any time you want to know if the upload is still progressing.

If you're talking about the user opening a new browser window on the same upload URL but starting a new upload page and you somehow want to reflect in that new page what is happening in some other browser window, then that is not as simple and you would probably need to use either some interwindow communication or some cross window state (such as local storage or cookie).

For a more specific recommendation, you will have to explain what you mean by "user navigates back to the upload page".  If a page doing an upload was ever closed, the upload would stop anyway, right?

Comment: I guess I should have explained what the html5 history api does. Basically I need to do this because a user can change the page without a full page refresh, hence `changePage`.